# Does docker compose log environment variables loaded by env_file?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, environment-variables, app-secret, docker-logs

We can load random data into a container like this:

`vars.env`

```ini
FOO=123
BAR=abc
```

`docker-compose.yml`

```yaml
my_service:
  image: my_image
  env_file:
    - ./vars.env
  # ...
```

Is it possible that those environment variables will be logged?

(I'm running the container on linux.)

Comment: I don't think Docker/Compose normally logs them, but it's not _impossible_.  Nothing stops the container code from running `env`, and if you can run `docker` commands, you can see a lot of things (and pretty easily root the host).  What's your specific need here?

Comment: @DavidMaze Yes, and one should also consider that the processes in the container could also log the env vars. My need: I'm looking for a safe way to pass secrets into a container without somehow leaking them. Secrets are no good as I'm not using swarm, and secrets-as-bind-mounts are also no good as they are mounted as root:root and the container I'm using (gitea) runs as non-root so can't access them. I might have to live with the risk (regarding env vars) and be done with it.

Comment: Traditionally, if you don't believe environment variables can be trusted, the alternative is to pass values as files; in Docker/Compose you'd do this with a bind mount.  But it requires support in your application to read the file, and it can be a little harder to inject a dynamic value (like a cloud hostname or an actually-random password).

Comment: @DavidMaze Agreed, but as I mentioned above there's another reason, and that's they are mounted as `/run/secrets/FOO` and that file is `root:root` and the app in the container won't be able to read it if it runs as a non-root user. Hence my research into viability of just using env vars (not because I tolerate the risk, but for lack of any better option).

Answer (score 2):

Although I cannot exactly point you to a case where docker (and docker-compose) logs environment variables, I would imagine it's very much likely since docker does not treat `environment-variables` as `secrets`. Therefore, if you are concerned about your env variables getting logged, you should use `docker secrets` instead.

You should be able to find plenty of examples on the internet on how to utilize this Docker feature in docker-compose. Here's the official one for example: https://docs.docker.com/compose/use-secrets/

It's pretty simple to use but in this case, you can be 100% certain that your secret's plaintext values won't appear anywhere.

Comment: Agreed, however 1) docker secrets is only for swarm, which I'm not using; for those using swarm it's the perfect solution, and 2) for the secrets-as-mounted file in non-swarm, the files are mounted as root:root which means many (non-root user) containers cannot access them. That's why I am looking into using some other option. Sadly, all are insecure in some way or another.